# Navigate to Community Page with Url Parameter

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I have a community page with a lightning component on it that will load some details for a salesforce record. I'd like to load the page from another community page and pass the id of the record I'd like to load. It's essentially a detail page.

Using navigateTo('url':'myurl?id=[record_id]', isredirect=true) apears to load the page and change the browsers url, but the init event doesn't seem to get fired for my component. Is there some way to get the component to initialize properly? If I shift refresh after navigating to the page, it appears to initialize the component but it removes any query parameters

This may be a misunderstanding of how navigation should work in lightning / community builder. Any guidance is much appreciated

Comment: were you able to find a solution to this? trying to figure it out myself and so far only discovered a way to do this if you call an app (which obviously isn't the case), and a bunch of other vague answers..

Comment: Just re-found this post from a few years ago trying to find a solution for passing parameters to a url. Navigation in community builder is still a mess.